# How to display text in a new line even if it could fit in a single line?

Tags: css, word-wrap

I'm trying to achive a layout like this:

[image]

So the subtitle is always at least in the second line, even if it could fit in the first line next to the title. If the title is long and break into two or more lines, the subtitle should follow the title without breaking a new line.

This is what i did so far, but this solution is not perfect:

```css
div.data {
  background:white;
  position:relative;
  min-height: 2em;
  float:left;
  max-width:150px;
  margin: 50px;
}

.title {
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: white;
  z-index: 10;
}

.title span {
  position:relative;
}

.title span span {
  position:absolute;
  right:0px;
  opacity:1;
  top: 18px;
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: red;
}

span.subtitle {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  z-index: 5;
  display:block;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="data">
  <div class="title"><span>title  <span>subtitle</span></span></div>
  <span class="subtitle">subtitle</span>
</div>


<div class="data">
  <div class="title"><span>reaallllyyyy loooooong title  <span>subtitle</span></span></div>
  <span class="subtitle">subtitle</span>
</div>
```

Sorry about the question's title, thats the best i could come up with.

Comment: just a comment that CSS can not detect if text is wrapped. can you use javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 0):

I have simplied your HTML, I believe that you don't really want your current one.

Adding a pseudo element floated right seems to do what you want: force the subtitle to a new line only if it is on the first one:

The pseudoelement has a color for demo purposes, remove it in production

```css
.data {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  max-width: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.title {
  color: blue;
}

.subtitle {
  color: gray;
}

.title:before {
  content: " ";
  float: right;
  width: 150px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="data">
  <span class="title">title</span>
  <span class="subtitle">subtitle</span>
</div>
<div class="data">
  <span class="title">reaallllyyyy loooooong title</span>
  <span class="subtitle">subtitle</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This won't work with other text examples https://jsfiddle.net/wgngr17k/1/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, CSS can't detect when text has wrapped. Here is a jQuery solution. Someone may come up with a better way of doing this, but it is the best approach I could think of in a short space of time.

What I am doing it getting the width of the `.data` element, then cloning it and applying CSS to the clone to prevent the text from wrapping. I then compare the width of the existing and cloned element to determine whether the text has wrapped.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // iterate through .data elements
  $('.data').each(function() {

    // store width of currently iterated element
    var startTextWidth = $(this).width();

    // clone currently iterated element
    var clone = $(this).clone();

    // apply CSS to cloned element to prevent text wrapping.
    clone.css({
        position: "absolute",
        left: "-10000px",
        maxWidth: "none"
    }).appendTo("body");

    // get the width of the cloned element with the newly applied CSS
    textWidth = clone.width();
    
    // if cloned elements width is larger than the existing elements width then the text has wrapped
    if(textWidth > startTextWidth) {
      // apply display:inline to the .title element
      $(this).find('.title').css('display', 'inline');
    }
    
    // remove cloned element
    clone.remove();
  });
});
```

```css
div.data {
  background:white;
  position:relative;
  min-height: 2em;
  float:left;
  max-width:150px;
  margin: 50px;
}
.title {
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: white;
  z-index: 10;
}
.subtitle {
  color:grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data">
  <div class="title">title</div>
  <span class="subtitle">subtitle</span>
</div>
<div class="data">
  <div class="title">reaallllyyyy loooooong title</div>
  <span class="subtitle">subtitle</span>
</div>
```